# Rails uniqueness validation failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `SapEvento` model which belongs to `SapIntegracao` model. On SapEvento, I have the following validation:

```
  validates :params_operacao, uniqueness: true, if: :check_params

  def check_params
    self.sap_integracao_log.recebimento
  end
```

I'm doing that to prevent duplicate requests on a soap integration (sometimes the same xml comes multiple times). So the params I receive are saved on that :params_operacao attribute, as a string. But the problem is the validation in saving. When I receive the XML and create the `SapEvento` object by doing

```
evento_erro = sap_integracao_log.sap_eventos.create(
        evento_tipo: SapEvento.get_evento_tipo("Erro na Integração"),
        params_operacao: params.to_s,
        erro_descricao: (!transporte ? "Transporte não encontrado" : erro),
        reenviado: false,
        operacao: operacao
      )
```

it doesn't validate and permits to create another object, even if already exists an object with same :params_operacao value.

I debugged on `check_params` method:

```
logger.debug "recebimento #{self.sap_integracao_log.recebimento}"
logger.debug "count #{SapEvento.where(params_operacao: self.params_operacao).count}"
```

and `recebimento` is true and the count is bigger than 0... so it shouldn't permitt, right?

I also tried some other syntaxes, like:

```
validates :params_operacao, uniqueness: true, if: "self.sap_integracao_log.recebimento"
```

but none of these worked. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I also tried, on console, take the last `SapEvento.params_operacao` and create a new `SapEvento` doing `SapEvento.new(params_operacao: last_evento_params_operacao)` and save. It also doesn't give me any errors...

Comment: just `validates :params_operacao, uniqueness: true`?

Comment: @potashin it also creates!

Comment: @potashin put some edit that may be helpful

Comment: What's in your `params.to_s`?